# How to delete cookies in Nativescript

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am developing an iOS app using NativeScript using Angular. I have a webview in it. I want to delete all the cookies on click of a button. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for iOs you can user following code to delete each cookies inside the IOs WebView.

```
const cookies: any = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage.cookies;
    if (typeof cookies !== 'undefined') {
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.count; i++) {
            const cookie: NSHTTPCookie = <NSHTTPCookie>cookies.objectAtIndex(i);
            // let cookie: any = cookies[i];
            console.log(cookie);
            NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage.deleteCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
    console.log(NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage.cookies);
```

After the last console.log there shouldn't be any Cookies.

Kind regards